# search by name and number with the same change textbox in Visual studio

Tags: vb.net

I have this code to search in Access db with visual studio to search in SerialNumber column:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles        TextBox2.TextChanged
 if Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
 SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = ""
Else
 SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
End If
End Sub
```

What if I want to search also in "Name" column with the same changed textbox?

Data Type in serialnumber column is number and in Name text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all here to help me and gave me Ideas.

The solution I got it and did it is first I converted the serialnumber column data type from number to short text in MS Access DB then I used this code:

```
 SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'" & " OR  Name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Again Thank you for all :)

Answer (score 1):

The remarks in the [BindingSource.Filter Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) state

> To form a filter value, specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on. The accepted filter syntax depends on the underlying data source. If the underlying data source is a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView, you can specify Boolean expressions using the syntax documented for the [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

So, assuming the above condition is met and looking at the documented syntax:

```
SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("SerialNumber = '{0}' OR Name = '{0}'", TextBox2.Text)
```

You might want to replace any single quotes in `TextBox2.Text` with two single quotes to escape them.

Comment: I tried it and worked with search Seriannumber but when I put letter to search in Name column gave me this error: System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'

Comment: @MohammadKhaled Please edit the question to show the datatypes of the columns. I *guess* you need to remove the second pair of single quotes, as in `OR Name = {0}`. In which case you should make sure that there really is a number in the textbox.

Comment: I tried to remove single quotes but didn't work with me. What only solution I found is to convert the serial number column in DB to be like text then I used this : 
        SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'" & " OR Name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"